# Visualforce id error

Tags: visualforce, controller, custom-button

Hi Please find the below code where it is used to add multiple attachments at a time for a custom object .I am not able to add id of the custom object record. we have created a custom button by using the below VF page. we are getting an error required field missing and I am not able to pass id of the custom object. consider custom object name as TestObject. Please let me know how can i solve it.

```
        <apex:pageBlock title="Upload Multiple Attachment to Object">  
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >  
                <apex:commandButton value="Upload"  action="{!SaveAttachments}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageMessages id="MSG"/>  
            <apex:actionFunction name="ChangeCount" action="{!ChangeCount}"/>  
        <apex:pageblocksection >  

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
                    <apex:outputLabel value="How many files you want to upload?"/>  
                    <apex:selectList onchange="ChangeCount() ;" multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!FileCount}">  
                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="--None--" itemValue=""/>  
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!filesCountList}"/>  
                    </apex:selectList>  
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  

            </apex:pageblocksection>  
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Files" rendered="{!IF(FileCount != null && FileCount != '', true , false)}">  
                <apex:repeat value="{!allFileList}" var="AFL">  
                    <apex:inputfile value="{!AFL.body}" filename="{!AFL.Name}" />  


                </apex:repeat>  
            </apex:pageBlockSection>  
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

================controller====

```
public class Multiattachments {
public List<SelectOption> filesCountList {get; set;}  
 public String FileCount {get; set;}
 public List<Attachment> allFileList {get; set;} 
 public TestObject__c TO {get;set;} 

  public Multiattachments ()  
        {  
            //Initialize    
            filesCountList = new List<SelectOption>() ;  
            FileCount = '' ;  
            allFileList = new List<Attachment>() ;  

            //Adding values count list - you can change this according to your need  
            for(Integer i = 1 ; i < 11 ; i++)  
                filesCountList.add(new SelectOption(''+i , ''+i)) ;  
        }  



    public PageReference SaveAttachments() {

            ID accId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id');  
            if(accId == null || accId == '')  
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'No record is associated. Please pass record Id in parameter.'));  
            if(FileCount == null || FileCount == '')  
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select how many files you want to upload.'));  

            List<Attachment> listToInsert = new List<Attachment>() ;  

            //Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = accid, name=myfile.name, body = myfile.body);  
            for(Attachment a: allFileList)  
            {  
                if(a.name != '' && a.name != '' && a.body != null)  
                    listToInsert.add(new Attachment(parentId = accId, name = a.name, body = a.body)) ;  
            }  

            //Inserting attachments  
            if(listToInsert.size() > 0)  
            {  
                insert listToInsert ;  
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, listToInsert.size() + ' file(s) are uploaded successfully'));  
                FileCount = '' ;  
            }  
            else  
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select at-least one file'));  

            return null;  

    }
    public PageReference ChangeCount()  
        {  
            allFileList.clear() ;  
            //Adding multiple attachments instance  
            for(Integer i = 1 ; i <= Integer.valueOf(FileCount) ; i++)  
                allFileList.add(new Attachment()) ;  
            return null ;  
        }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is with the following line:

```
ID accId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id');
```

The function you are calling returns a string not an ID. Do the following:

```
String accId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id');
```